# How can i batch rename files to match a list of strings in a text file? (Windows 11)

Tags: rename, batch-processing, batch-rename

I would like to batch rename a large amount of photos to match lines of text I have in a txt file. I aligned the new names to the alphabetical order of my photos and have the same # of photos as I do lines of text so my goal is for them to sync properly from Top to Bottom. Is there a way I can accomplish this using Windows 11?

Here's an example...

```
Apple_12049.jpg   apple.jpg
Canon_10394.jpg  canon.jpg
Dodge_29-1.jpg   dodge.jpg
```

I have tried downloading many bulk renaming tools but have not found any that can match with lines of text.

Comment: Are you open to a Perl `file-rename` efficient solution?

Comment: I am open to anything I can use on my windows 11 pc that can accomplish it for free :)

Answer (score 0):

Perl's to the rescue! (wink @Choroba)

```
$ cd c:/path/to/directory/with/photos
$ perl -lane 'rename($F[0], $F[1])' file
```

If you don't have Perl, search for `Strawberry Perl downloads` in your preferred search engine
Hopefully **\_0< \_0< GO**

Comment: The issue is I do not have a text list of the actual photo files, only what I want to rename them to. Forgot to mention that part sorry about that! *E.g., I have 500 photos and a text file with 500 lines I wish the 500 photos to be renamed as from Top to Bottom (Alphabetical order) that way the photos within a specific directly can be renamed to each line (line by line from top to bottom). I hope i made better sense

Comment: Was reading to fast your question, post edited accordingly

Comment: Thanks a lot for assisting but to clarify should I place my text file (list.txt) into the directory of the photos then cd into the folder using CMD and run the following?

$ perl -lane 'rename($F[0], $F[1])' list.txt

?

Comment: You can place list.txt where you want, not an issue. In current directory: `list.txt` or elsewhere `C/User/X/FOO/BAR/file.txt`. But run the command line in the directory where you have files to rename

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell for this:

```bash
cd c:\path\to\directory\with\photos
foreach($line in Get-Content c:\path\to\renaming\file.txt) {Rename-Item -path ($line -split '\s+')[0] -newname ($line -split '\s+')[1]}
```